# Joining Dataframes in Pandas deletes an existing column

Tags: numpy, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Pandas, I have two data frames

a > date           location               quantity       sales 
    2015-11-01     LA                      30             12
    2015-11-01     BOS                     24             15 
      .......
    36000 rows

b > Location  Identifier
      LA         Yes
      BOS        Yes

.....
20 rows

I would like to create a new dataFrame
date           location               quantity       sales        Identifier
    2015-11-01     LA                      30             12        Yes
    2015-11-01     BOS                     24             15        Yes
      .......
    36000 rows

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Pandas can do a number of different SQL-like joins. Assuming each `Location` has a unique `Identifier`, a join using the `'inner'` strategy should do what you're asking for:

```
pd.merge(a, b, how='inner', on=['Location'])
```

You can find more detailed documentation and examples in the [pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging).